# How to trigger certain config changes manually?

Tags: android

Here are the list of config changes on Android:

```
"mcc", "mnc", "locale",
"touchscreen", "keyboard", "keyboardHidden",
"navigation", "screenLayout", "fontScale", "uiMode",
"orientation", "screenSize", "smallestScreenSize" , etc etc
```

I know that for example, i can change the locale in the device or orientation and this will trigger a config change. But Some of them i don't know how to trigger then. For example, navigation and uiMode ?  and i am assuming mcc and mnc can be changed by swapping a SIM card but i'm not certain.  How can i see a methods to trigger all these config changes ? For example, is there a adb command for it ?

Answer (score 2):

hey i found a [list online](http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.ca/2013/05/android-configchanges-attributes.html) of all the triggers for config changes and thought i would share it:

[image]